# React functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I create the next class

```
export default class WaterCount extends Component {

    static defaultProps = {};

     state = {
        currentVolume: 0
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }


    render() {
        return (

                {/*Start of buttons container*/}
                <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                    <Button onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                currentVolume: this.state.currentVolume + 10
            }, function () {
                alert(this.state.currentVolume);
            });
                    }} title="Hi!"/>
                </View>

    }
}
```

If i define function for button like in example above, all works fine.

But if i do the same things by this way:

```
export default class WaterCount extends Component {


     static defaultProps = {};

        state = {
            currentVolume: 0
        };

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

        }


        render() {
            return (

                    {/*Start of buttons container*/}
                    <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                        <Button onPress={this.addVolume} title="Hi!"/>
                    </View>

            );
        }

        addVolume() {
            this.setState({
                currentVolume: this.state.currentVolume + 10
            }, function () {
                alert(this.state.currentVolume);
            });
        }

}
```

It drops to me the `error : undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.currentVolume').` Can you say where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Button onPress={this.addVolume} title="Hi!"/>
```

needs to be

```
 <Button onPress={this.addVolume.bind(this)} title="Hi!"/>
```

Basically, this is a common mistake for people just getting familiar with React. You'll need to provide context for the method, because React doesn't do that automatically for you.

---

Read more [here](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/).

Alternatively, you could use following snippet in your constructor

```
this.addVolume = this.addVolume.bind(this);
```

Comment: jsx-no-bind will blame you!

Comment: // eslint-disable-line jsx-no-bind 
OK, I plead guilty and provided alternative syntax.